# Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move 'C:\xampp

Tags: php

Trying to upload image and make a thumbnail from the original while preserving both in spec. dir. in C:/
But warning message occures

> "Warning:
>   move_uploaded_file(C:/upload_test26726_1341621867827_8230312_n.jpg):
>   failed to open stream: Permission denied in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\p-t-b\classes\Ps2\ThumbnailUpload.php on line 52"...
>   and... "Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move
>   'C:\xampp\tmp\phpE0EA.tmp' to
>   'C:/upload_test26726_1341621867827_8230312_n.jpg' in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\p-t-b\classes\Ps2\ThumbnailUpload.php on line 52"

[problematic line 52](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5TtKd.jpg)

Comment: your path is not correct to where your move your file its  C:/upload_test/26726_1341621867827_8230312_n.jpg

Comment: As @RanjeetSingh said, there's a problem in your path. You have a forward slash after your C:

Comment: It's not about a fwd slash, they have to be like that...the problem was i omitted a end fwd slash - Problem Solved :)